# Can I uninstall a Parental Control UWP app if a condition is met?

Tags: uwp, uninstallation, parental-control

I'm building a parental control application in UWP and I need to be able to uninstall the application only if the user (the child basically) introduces some correct credentials (username and password). Otherwise, the child can simply uninstall the application and bypass the parental control system that I built.

I already did this in Windows Forms using Visual Studio Installer: I created an Installer class and on the Uninstall step I check the credentials (using a Custom Action).

Can I do this in UWP? Are there any workarounds that can achieve the same effect?

Thank you respectfully.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert your Windows Forms application to UWP app by using [Desktop Bridge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/desktop).

The detailed steps are on document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately I have a bad news to give you and a beautiful, the bad that uwp are managed by windoes as an app and not installed software normally so you can not bypass windows store (as he is managing the installed apps), the good news that you it will be enough in the windows settings to set the uninstallation with a password